# Image Editor actions throws "Parameter not valid."

Tags: content-editor, azure, media-library, paas

Image editor doesn't function after deploying to the azure environments. This seems to be the case for our Dev, Test and Acceptance environments.

When using **Crop** or **Rotate** or **Flip**:
[image: On crop]
[image]

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parameter is not valid.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.]
   System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename) +183
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.Imager.Imager.Crop(String file, String work, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height) +151
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.Imager.ImagerForm.Crop() +280
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.Execute(CommandContext context) +622
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.SendMessage(Message message) +65
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Dispatcher.Dispatch(Message message, CommandContext context) +102
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.Execute(CommandContext context) +622
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.Dispatch(String command) +231
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RaiseEvent() +124
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +801
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +200
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +7479
```

When using Resize:
[image]

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\-\temp\imager.20190313t1613332060.jpeg.aspx
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: D:\home\site\wwwroot\-\temp\imager.20190313t1613332060.jpeg.aspx

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[FileNotFoundException: D:\home\site\wwwroot\-\temp\imager.20190313t1613332060.jpeg.aspx]
   System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement) +246
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.Imager.ImagerResizeForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +142

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +128
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +142
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +597
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +154
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4082
```

The /Temp/ folder looks like the following:

[image]

This seems very different from the temp folder in my local development instance of sitecore. Where I can see the temp files

Comment: I think the answer may be as simple as; `System.Drawing` is not supported on Azure Web Apps. And I don't think Sitecore has an alternative in place. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924122/can-system-drawing-be-used-in-an-azure-web-site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure but try to change the setting for "tempFolder" in Sitecore.config to "/temp". The setting is configured/overwritten in Sitecore.Azure.Settings.config:

```
<sc.variable name="tempFolder" value="/temp" />
```

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the answer. Thanks.